# Validate xml from visual basic

Tags: xml, vb.net, sql-server-2008, xsd, xsd-validation

I'm using .NET with Visual Basic. I have a code that executes a SQL query to a SQL server and the result is stored in XML in a XML file. Now I manually created an XSD file in the same directory as the XML result and want to know how can I do to validate XML with XSD from VB.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Dim tr as XmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(xmlFilePath)
Dim vr as XmlValidatingReader = new XmlValidatingReader(tr)
Dim xsc as XmlSchemaCollection = new XmlSchemaCollection
xsc.Add(xsdTargetNamespace, xsdFilePath)
vr.Schemas.Add(xsc)
```

see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwhexew4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for details.